# click one element to trigger another's link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, triggers, click

I have two element and I want to click one to trigger the others link.

I've tried two ways. Both click functions work as button 1 turns red on click however it's not triggering the link. Any ideas what I'm missing from the below?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a class="link" href="http://google.com">Button 1</a>
<div class="clickThis">i want to click this one</div>


<script>

var clickThis = document.getElementsByClassName('clickThis');
var link = document.getElementsByClassName('link');


$(clickThis).click(function(){
    $(link).css({"color": "red"});
    $(link).trigger('click');
});

$(document).on('click', clickThis, function(event) { 
event.preventDefault(); 
    $(link).css({"color": "red"});
    $(link).click();
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS should look like this:

```
var clickThis = '.clickThis';
var link = '.link';

$(clickThis).click(function(){
    $(link).css({"color": "red"});
    $(link)[0].click();
});
```

Remember when you select classes they return more than one element, so jQuery won't know which element to click, in your case you only have one element with that class but you still need to say which one, with `[0]`.

Working jsfiddle sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/qf0ta0cx/1/

I added `target="_blank"` in the `a` tag just to test it without refreshing the page everytime I click it but opening the link in a new tab, you can remove it according to your preference.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you're overcomplicating it.

I don't think you need jQuery to achieve this.

Here's what I could figure after reading your code :

When targetting element with `getElementsByClassName` you're getting an array, so get first index to get what you need :

```
 var clickThis = document.getElementsByClassName('clickThis')[0];
 var link = document.getElementsByClassName('link')[0];
```

You can listen to click on an element with `onclick` and trigger a click with `.click()`, easy :

```
clickThis.onclick = function() {
    link.click();
};
link.onclick = function () {
    link.style.color = 'red';
}
```

And... this is all you need to make it work.

Sometimes, vanilla javascript is better :D

Look at this jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/27of62dc/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help Yoann.

Answer (score 1):

When an element with the clickThis class is clicked, it will trigger a click on the elements with the link class.  If you have multiple elements with the link class, you may want to use an element id.

```
$('.clickThis').on('click',function() {
    console.log('div');
    $('.link').css({"color": "red"});
    $('.link').click();
});

$('.link').click(function() {
    console.log('clicked!');
    window.location = $(this).prop('href');
});
```

Comment: You still didn't solve the issue, you need to indicate which element to click, `$('.link')[0].click()` or use an ID.